# Al loguearse cargue una tabla diferente a la tabla de usuarios

Tags: php, sql

Le explico bien, existen dos usuarios: médico y psicólogo.
De tablas tengo: la de (usuarios). la de (psicólogo citas). la de (medico citas).

cuando el medico inicie sesión carguen sus datos que están en la tabla de usuarios ejemplo de la tabla: user, pass, nombre, identificación. ya eso lo pude lograr con un session_start.

pero cuando ese usuario medico entre se cargue una tabla con su información de la tabla medico citas en una sola página.

pero si psicólogo inicia sesión quiero que en esa tabla de esa misma página aparezcan los datos de la tabla psicólogo citas.

```
SELECT * FROM medicos ORDER BY medfecha, medhora");
```

Comment: Ese `select` te sirve para seleccionar los datos de la tabla médicos. Si quieres los datos del psicologo tendrías que cambiarlo por algo como `SELECT * from psicologos ORDER BY [las columnas que quieras que se ordenen]`

Comment: si coloco SELECT * from psicologos si el usuario medico entra le saldran la informacion del psicologo. yo quiero que cuando entre medico cargue la tabla medico. pero cuando entre psicologo cargue la tabla psicologo.  en SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY  coloco usuarios pero me muestra es la tabla de los usuarios

Comment: ¡Vaya joven! **El sentido común** indica que en php tendrías que poner un condicional que revise qué usuario se logueó, y en base a eso usar una u otra sentencia sql...

Comment: Te recomiendo leas sobre control de sesiones y te dejaré [éste tutorial](http://www.ingdiaz.org/control-sesiones-autenticacion-usuarios-usando-php-mysql/) que encontré. Con el control de sesiones puedes mostrar lo que necesites a cada usuario sin pasar a llevar tus consultas y las harás mas dinámicas.

Comment: con el session_start(); puedo cargar los datos de usuario logueado <?php echo $_SESSION['nombres'];?> / lo que quiero es que cada usuario logueado cargue una tabla segun su perfil si entra medico aparece su nombre y la tabla de medico con sus citas / si entra psicologo carga la tabla de psicologo con sus citas. no se si me explico muchas gracias por la info.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, como te dijo @AntonioVenerosoContreras debes verificar qué tipo de usuario es el logeado antes de hacer la consulta. Algo como `if($_SESSION['identificacion'] == 'psicologo'){ //Consulta en caso de psicólogo }else{ //Consulta en caso de médico}'`

Comment: @AndySamuel  no se donde colocarlo te muestro el código: 
  <?php 
$mensaje='';
try{
 $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test','root','');
}catch(PDOException $e){
 echo "Error: ". $e->getMessage();
}

$consulta = $conexion -> prepare("
 SELECT * FROM medicina ORDER BY medfecha, medhora");

$consulta ->execute();
$consulta = $consulta ->fetchAll();
if(!$consulta){
 $mensaje .= 'NO HAY CITAS AGENDADAS';
}
?>

Comment: asi identifico al usuario: <?php 
session_start();

$varsesion = $_SESSION['usuario'];
if($varsesion == null || $varsesion = '') {
  header('Location: ../index.html');
}
 ?>